# Need help with .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all image requests from `site.com/folder1/folder2/images/name.jpg` to `site.com/folder3/folder4/folder5/images/name.jpg`

Where `name` is dynamic

Comment: are folder* dynamic? or static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule folder1/folder2/images/(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ /folder3/folder4/folder5/images/$1.$2 [L,QSA]

# If you only have jpg
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/images/(.*)\.jpg$ http://site.com/folder3/folder4/folder5/images/$1.jpg [L,QSA]
```